# How to update a QLabel to display a QImage

Tags: c++, qt

I may be misunderstanding how to do this, hopefully somebody can clarify.

I have placed a `QLabel` on my main window from inside Qt Designer.  Currently, it just displays the letters "`TextLabel`" when I run the program.

I have a line edit where I type in the path to an image, which then loads the image as a `QImage` into memory (I have this working).

Finally, I want to display this `QImage`.  I was told this can be done by `QLabels`.  I have done the following, but nothing is happening:

```
ui.input_label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(my_qimage));
```

Why is nothing happening?  How can I display this image?

Comment: What is your criteria for knowing the `QImage` is valid after loading?

Comment: @ArnoldSpence Sorry, I don't understand.  It is for experimental purposes, so I know it's valid because I am inputting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure the image file is ok but then the problem is probably with loading the file into the `QImage`. If you are calling `QImage::load()`, you are probably getting a return value of `false`.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm actually loading it through OpenCV, and converting to a QImage as outlined in ypnos's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590950/how-to-update-a-qlabel-to-display-a-qimage.  I display the image in OpenCV and it is fine.  I don't have to do anything to update the main window to view the label's update?

Comment: Oh, I was assuming you were loading the image from a file directly from `QImage`. Once you call 'setPixmap()', the label should update itself and show the image.